# rating bar is not showing in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating an app in that I'm allow client to rate the app.

I have two issues

**FIRST**.

I have added Rating bar in Alert dialog but dont know why its getting overwrite on button which i have created for submit the ratings.
I have tried with margin-top for button still its not working

[image: Here is the image of alert dialog]

**Second.**

On submit it also not showing toast message.

Code for Alert Dialog

```
if (id == R.id.nav_rate) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(homeActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingbar,null);
        final RatingBar ratebar = (RatingBar)mView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        Button btnSubmit=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubRating);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, ((int) rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            }
        });
        mBuild.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog=mBuild.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="1"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnSubRating"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubRating"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: If you want to give width and height give them based on device screen  size , Submit is ok but you use an int instead of   CharSequence text,  a use toast correctly `Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, ""+rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @Charuka ok i have made it correct but still its not showing the toast

Comment: it goes inside the block only you change the numbers `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` its a change listener

Comment: @Charuka So what i do now ??

Comment: change the rate and hit that button toast will be happy to see u

Comment: or  `ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });` bring this block outside in you buttonclick

Comment: @Charuka ok i will do it and let u inform coz i've got emergency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    private float rateValue;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(homeActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingbar,null);

            final RatingBar ratebar = (RatingBar)mView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    rateValue = rating;
                    Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, ""+rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Button btnSubmit=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubRating);
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, ""+rateValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mBuild.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog=mBuild.create();
            dialog.show();

}

}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rate_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="1"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSubRating"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubRating"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and one more thing after clicking on submit i want to close dialog box i knwo the `dismiss();` but where should i use this?

Comment: inside `btnSubmit` click after whatever your process that you do inside that,at the moment below the toast will be good

Comment: i have tried but its showing error `cannot resolve the symbol`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133099/discussion-between-nilesh-indalkar-and-charuka).

Answer (score 0):

you have fixed the size of dialog which is not allowing rating bar to fit into it.

replace `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);`

with `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(800, 600);`

In your Activity

create class variable :-

```
 float rating=0;
```

and use it to store rating on click of rating

```
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingbar,null);
    final RatingBar ratebar = (RatingBar)mView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    Button btnSubmit=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubRating);

ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
        rating=v;
    }
});
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, String.valueOf(ratebar.getRating()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    mBuild.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog=mBuild.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: ok i have mistakenly add those code `getWindow` which i've removed now     its showing rating bar properly but how can i work on submit button which i mentioned in question?

Comment: ok i used this but its showing only 0 rating on submit button

Comment: You have to set some rating to see rating.

Comment: ok its showing initial value which i set on `float rating=0;` whenever i click on 4 rating its showing only 0 which i set initially

Comment: have you assigned  rating=v; for rating ?

Comment: use updated code String.valueOf(ratebar.getRating()) in toast you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuild.show();
```

instead:

```
AlertDialog dialog=mBuild.create();
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
dialog.show();
```

Moreover: android:layout_above are only allowed on RelativeLayout (so delete it)